# How can I express, "The set of integers greater than x and less than y"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I know I could express it this way (x = 0, y = 10):
$$
\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , 6, 7, 8, 9 \}
$$
in simple cases.

This is what I could come up with for the more general case:
$$
\mathbb I = \{ i_n | i_n > y, i_n < y, i \in \mathbb Z \}
$$
How can I express this correctly or formally?

Comment: You could do $(x,y)\cap \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What is $i_n$? (Is it the same as $i$? Is there a reason for the subscript?) How could we have $i_n>y$ and $i_n<y$?

Comment: I find the close vote puzzling. The question is perfectly clear.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I was trying to say $i_n$ are the members of the set. `Henning Makholm` made it clear they are not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make your suggestion more in line with usual notation, write
$$ I = \{ n\in\mathbb Z \mid x<n<y \} $$
There's no need to put a subscript on the variable; it just gets a new value for each element of the set. (The variable is *bound* by the set builder notation, and is not visible outside it).

In situations where you don't need to be completely formal, it can be simpler and more readable just to write
$$ \{x+1,x+2,\ldots,y-1\} $$
-- especially if $x$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathbb{Z}\supset\mathbb{I}:=\{n:x<n<y,\space n\in\mathbb{Z}\}\\
\text{Or, }\mathbb{Z}\supset(x,y)\cap\mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 1):

The [set comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) you are looking for is usually either:

$$I = \{i \in \mathbb N \mid x < i \land i < y\}$$

or

$$I = \{i \mid i \in \mathbb N \land x < i \land i < y\}$$

in general

$$\{\text{variable} \in \text{larger set} \mid \text{filter}(\text{variable})\}$$